# How to use initialization lists to create members in a linked list C++

Tags: c++, linked-list

I have an object oriented program that has three classes, one base class and two derived from it. as such am using a linked list to hold members created after the program is complied and executed however i wish to create members for the linked list that will load up when the program is executed.

i have the linked list header file and the base class header file, in which header/cpp file do i use an initialization list and how do  implement it?

Comment: Where is the data of the objects you want to add come from?

Comment: since they are new objects i have will assign new data to them

Comment: `struct Node {int x; Node* next;}; Node* root = new Node{1,new Node{2, new Node{3,NULL}}};`

Comment: you'll find an example in the `<list>` header file in the standard library. `std::list<>` has such a constructor.

Comment: @user3919767 Where does the data come from, a file, hardcoded?

Comment: @NeilKirk no its new data am adding to the linked list, its pretty much made up data am adding to see if the program runs as intended plus i have other functions that require data to be tested